# Fix div to bottom and keep it responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this case has been answered before - but I didn't find anything useful that could solve the problem...

I'm trying to set chat box `div` to the bottom of a page, I need it to be placed but not fixed and I also need to keep the page as much responsive as possible.

As you can see [Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/fpucjmxm/8/), the chat box is floating to the left of right `div` - I wish to have a space between them and make the chat opened up rather then down...

Here are some pictures with more explicit explanation

Here is what I wish to achieve :

[image]

Here is what I wish to achieve when the chat window is open:

[image]

Here is my current state :

[image]

Comment: Can we use `position: fixed` to make the div in the bottom. It can be made responsive even its fixed.

Comment: Thanks....i've tried....it makes the div float...

Comment: Rise -  the fiddle is in the post - and here https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/fpucjmxm/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the Answer you are looking for please check this, Its the `Fork` or your code.

i just added some extra style to your `.faq_chat` class.

```
.faq_chat{
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    width: 66.66666667%;
    background-color: #d2f1f0 ;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;//my style
    right: 0;//my style
    bottom: 0;//my style
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ckdL1fws/2/)**

Comment: Jithin Raj P R - Thanks A LOT !

Answer (score 0):

```
#div{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: position: absolute for such

Comment: with position: absolute i have to set left to place it ....so i have to put accurate size so it's not responsive

Comment: you can use % or vw to achieve this, thats the only thing I can think of for this situation

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of this `css`

```
.faq_cont_left {
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333333%;
    height: 800px;
}
```

In above css you are giving height `800px` which is 4 times higher than below block css

```
.faq_cont_right {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    width: 66.66666667%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In this css you are giving 200px. So you can do it like this

- You can decrease height of `.faq_cont_left` to `200px`
- or you can increase height of `.faq_cont_right` to `800px`

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can see with flex if is what's you've except.

> Flex guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:6px;
  background:red;
}

.my-app { /** Or just use "body" for your app container, if you want **/
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background:#f5f5f5;
}

.header {
  background:lightgreen;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  color:#fff;
}

.somecontent {
  background:tomato;
  padding:20px 0;
  margin:10px 0;
  color:#fff;
}

.chat {
  background:lightblue;
  margin:auto 0 5px 0;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-app">
  <div class="header">
    My app name
  </div>
  <div class="somecontent">
    Some content...
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
    My beautiful chat
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because of position. You need to set fixed position of your div at bottom.

> position:fixed

Here I update your [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fpucjmxm/9/) please check it.